# Exterior product of differential forms

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I have $\omega_1 \cdots \omega_k$ k  linearly independent 1-forms. I need to show that 2-forms $\omega_i \wedge \omega_j$ are linear independent when $i<j$
$$$$
$f_1, \cdots, f_k$ are linear independent means that $f_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge  f_k ≠ 0 $
$$$$
Let $k=3$. We have 3 2-forms for $i<j$. 
$$\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2, \omega_1 \wedge \omega_3, \omega_2 \wedge \omega_3$$
Let's look at $(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) \wedge (\omega_2 \wedge \omega_3)$. Exterior product is associative, so $(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) \wedge (\omega_2 \wedge \omega_3) = \omega_1 \wedge (\omega_2 \wedge \omega_2) \wedge \omega_3 = 0$
Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Your definition of linear independence is only true for one-forms.

Comment: @MikeHawk I can't find definition for two forms..........

Comment: There's no special definition for two forms. You just have to show that no non-trivial linear combination of them can be zero.

Comment: What is your definition of the space of 2-forms?

Answer (score 1):

For $i>j$ it is obvious that $\omega_i \wedge \omega_j$ is not linear independent with other forms because $\omega_i \wedge \omega_j = - \omega_j \wedge \omega_i$

lets see case $i<j$.
Asume the opposite, we have $a, b, c$ not equal to $0$ at the same time and we can and $i<j<k$. $$a\cdot(\omega_i \wedge \omega_k) +b\cdot(\omega_j \wedge \omega_k) + c\cdot(\omega_i \wedge \omega_j)=0$$
This can be truth only when $(\omega_i \wedge \omega_k) = (\omega_j \wedge \omega_k) =(\omega_i \wedge \omega_j)=0$ and we got a contradiction.